# Java file to create invoice from a txt file throwing NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: java, exception, filereader

What im trying to do is read a text file that contains

> account_number time_of_call minutes 10011 20:00 10.2 10011 13:23 12.3
>   10033 01:00 34.0

and im suppose to bill the customer with this

> $10/month base fee per account
>  $0.10 per minute for calls that started
>   between 8:00 AM and 10:00 PM, inclusive 
> $0.05 per minute all other
>   times

Ive gotten the answer and the format im suppose to put it in but im getting a java.util.NoSuchElementException and i cant seem to figure it out.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;


public class PhoneBill {
    Vector data;
    Vector processed = new Vector();

    Vector markProcessed = new Vector();
    public void readFile(String inFileStr)
    {
        String str = "";
        data = new Vector<LineItem>();
        FileReader fReader;
        InputStream inFileStream;
         try{
        fReader = new FileReader(inFileStr);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!= null){
                if (line.indexOf("_") != -1)
                    continue;
                else
                  if (!line.isEmpty()){
                    data.add(new LineItem(line.trim()));

                  }
            }

            br.close(); 
        }       
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    public void processCharges()
    {
        System.out.println ("Invoice");
        System.out.println ("--------------------------");
        System.out.println ("Account   " + "Amount Due ");
        double total = 0.0;
        double lCharges =0;
        boolean done = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++ ){
            LineItem li =  (LineItem)data.get(j);
            String accNum = li.getAccountNum();
            if (j > 0){
                done = checkProcessed(accNum);}
            else
                processed.add(accNum);
            if (!done){
                   lCharges = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
              String acc = ((LineItem)data.get(i)).getAccountNum();
              if (acc.equals(accNum) && !done)
              lCharges += processItemCharges(accNum);
              done = checkProcessed(accNum);
            }
            lCharges+=10.0;
            System.out.format ("%s" + "      $%.2f%n",accNum, lCharges);
            processed.add(accNum);
             total += lCharges;
            }

        }

        System.out.println ("--------------------------");
        System.out.format ("%s" + "      $%.2f%n","Total", total);
    }
    private boolean checkProcessed(String accNum){
        if (processed.contains(accNum))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    private double processItemCharges(String accNum)
    {
        double charges = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            if(((LineItem)data.get(i)).getAccountNum().equals(accNum))
                charges += ((LineItem)data.get(i)).getCharges();
        }
        return charges;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PhoneBill pB =  new PhoneBill();
        pB.readFile("input_data.txt");
        pB.processCharges();
    }

    class LineItem{
        String accNum ;
        String timeOfCall;
        double mins;
        double amountDue;
        boolean counted = false;

        public LineItem(String accStr)
        {
            processAccount(accStr);
        }

        private void processAccount(String accStr){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(accStr);
            accNum = (String)st.nextElement();
            timeOfCall = (String) st.nextElement();
            mins = Double.parseDouble((String) st.nextElement());
            if (timeOfCall.compareTo("08:00")>0 && timeOfCall.compareTo("22:00")<0)
                amountDue = mins*0.10;
            else
                amountDue = mins*0.05;
        }

        public String getAccountNum()
        {
            return accNum;
        }

        public double getCharges()
        {
            return amountDue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The NoSuchElement exception stack trace should include the line number that shows where in your code the error occurred at. What does it say?

Comment: It prints out in my console in eclipse ontop of my output but no line number indication.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't help us so much because you didn't provide the line of code where the exception has been generated.
By the way, I could bet that your exception is raised from one of the calls to

```
st.nextElement()
```

Ok, I know that this doesn't help you so much; I think that could be much more useful for you to known that the best way for handle exception during the early phases of development is to call:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(e.toString());
```

I hope this advice could help you.

Comment: The guys which have commented your post was waiting for the stack trace produced by printStackTrace, when one doesn't provide the stack trace is really hard to find out where it came out. If you are new you should bear in mind, if you are an expert likely it was a little mistake so don't pay attention to what I've said :)